# Facebook login and grunt server

Tags: facebook-graph-api, angularjs, gruntjs

I would like to test the facebook login of my web application,

Right now my Site URL in my Facebook app is this: `http://localhost:8080/#/SignIn`

I am using grunt (grunt server) to execute my application and when I try to access to the FB login I get this error:

```
Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Do I need to set up an Apache server for achive Facebook Connect locally?

Answer (score 0):

The grunt server should be fine (I use it with no trouble)

In the 'Basic' settings of your facebook app it asks you for a URL (in my case it's the Canvas URL).  In that URL you need to have `http://localhost:8080`.  When you're ready to deploy you can change the URL to your real host.

Comment: Finally I set up a Apache server, and it worked, I just added an url to the hosts file (localhost.com:8080) and updated the Facebook WebSite URL to that one, once I did that everything started to work